# Best Base for Radix Sort

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting, radix-sort, radix

I have read several sources about this topic.  However, I am having trouble figuring out exactly what these formulas mean.  It seems that Radix Sort is Linear when b = n.  Does this mean, I should set the base to the length of the array?

If I have an array of 100 million integers, with a range from 0 to 1 billion, I should choose base 100 million?

If this is not correct, please try to dumb it down for me.  Most examples with Radix Sort I can find only have base 10 or base 2, so either they are slow for arrays larger than 10 or 2 respectively, or I just don't get it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

Radix sort isn't actually linear time when you set the base to be the number of entries in the array. The runtime of radix sort is O(n log<sub>b</sub> U), where n is the total number of elements in the array, b is the chosen base, and U is the maximum number in the array. If you set b = n, then the runtime is O(n log<sub>n</sub> U) = O(n log U / log n). Asymptotically, this is really great!

In practice, though, other factors tend to be much more important in evaluating radix sort. One aspect is the cost of splitting the numbers into individual digits. Using a base that's a power of two, this is just a simple bitshift. With other bases, you may need to use (relatively) more expensive divisions, which can hurt a bit. More importantly, though, there's locality of reference. If you use base b, then you'll have b different arrays into which the elements are getting dropped. If you choose b to be too high, then you might get poor caching performance when appending elements to the ends of the bucket arrays, and this can actually cause performance degradation.

Probably the best idea would be to actually profile the program on different base choices and see what's best. From experience, when I've tried using base-n radix sort, I've found it to be slower than a standard base-2 radix sort on large inputs, predominantly due to locality issues. I would guess that 2 isn't an ideal base for the radix sort, but something large like 2<sup>16</sup> might start suffering from cache misses. Try experimenting and let us know what you find!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, you said "using base-n radix sort, I've found it to be slower than a standard base-2 radix sort on large inputs". And then you say,"I would guess that 2 isn't an ideal base for the radix sort". when base-2 is faster than base-n, why do you say  latter statement?

Comment: @chandresh That statement was primarily meant as "I don't have any a priori reason to believe that two is the best of all possible bases." It's quite possible that it is the best, but without having done more testing I can't say for sure.

Comment: OK. I would like to receive your comments on my Q here: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32128/on-non-comparison-based-sorting-algorithm

Answer (score 2):

For your case, best Radix sort base is 2^16 (65536), or 2^8 (256).
in 1st case, you will sort array for two move for each element, in 2nd - for 4 moves.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this value would be the best?

Comment: Because of this is 1/2 or 1/4 of sizeof(int). With 256, you will use less additional memory, but 4 moves total. With 256*256, you will reach result in 2 moves only (for eqch int), but you need significant extra memory for counters: sizeof(int) * 2 * 256*256 bytes = 512Mb.